# Can someone please check the given code? How can I save the result of GraphicsGrid as pdf?

Tags: plotting, save

I want to have these 3 plots together vertically

```
P1 = Plot[{0, If[Sin[x π] >= 0, 1000]}, {x, 0, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1000], Thickness[.04]]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 6, AspectRatio -> 1/40, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0}}]

P2 = Plot[{0, If[Cos[x π] >= 0, 1000]}, {x, 50, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1000], Thickness[.04]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/40, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{50, 100}, {0, 0}}]

P3 = Plot[{0, If[Sin[x π] < 0, 1000]}, {x, 100, 150}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[-1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Green, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1000], Thickness[.04]]},
   AspectRatio -> 1/40, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{100, 150}, {0, 0}}]
```

I use this code

```
Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{P1}, {P2}, {P3}}], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Green}, {Style["a", 10], 
    Style["b", 10], Style["c", 10]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

and I expect the result to be like

[image]

But what I see is

[image]

How can I save the result of this code as the first picture?

Comment: If you add the option `ItemAspectRatio->1/10` to your GraphicsGrid it seems to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Column` in place `GraphicsGrid`.

```
Legended[Column[{P1, P2, P3}], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Green}, {Style["a", 10], 
    Style["b", 10], Style["c", 10]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

I get:

[image: stacked plots]

**Update: Use ImageSizeMultipliers style option**

Normally, display functions such as `Column`, `Grid` and `Row` automatically reduce the size of graphics. However, there's a simple option, [`ImageSizeMultipliers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html), that adjusts the size of the graphics. I've added `BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1., 1.}]` to increase the size of the graphics.

```
Legended[
 Column[{P1, P2, P3}, 
  BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1., 1.}], 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Green}, {Style["a", 10], 
    Style["b", 10], Style["c", 10]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: with ImageSizeMultipliers option]

**Using GraphicsGrid**

Alternatively, some modifications to the plot options: add `PlotRange`, adjust `If` values, (`Opacity` value is 0 to 1), set `AspectRatio` to 1/20. Then add `Show[P1, ImageSize -> Full]` to `GraphicsGrid`.

```
P1 = Plot[{0, If[Sin[x \[Pi]] >= 0, 1]}, {x, 0, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Red, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.04]]}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 6, PlotRange -> {1, 1.1},
  AspectRatio -> 1/20, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{0, 50}, {0, 0}}];

P2 = Plot[{0, If[Cos[x \[Pi]] >= 0, 1]}, {x, 50, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Blue, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.04]]},
  PlotRange -> {1, 1.1}, AspectRatio -> 1/20, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{50, 100}, {0, 0}}];

P3 = Plot[{0, If[Sin[x \[Pi]] < 0, 1]}, {x, 100, 150}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[White, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], 
     Thickness[0]], 
    Directive[Green, CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[1], Thickness[.04]]},
  PlotRange -> {1, 1.1}, AspectRatio -> 1/20, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {{100, 150}, {0, 0}}];

Legended[GraphicsGrid[{{Show[P1, ImageSize -> Full]}, {Show[P2, 
     ImageSize -> Full]}, {Show[P3, ImageSize -> Full]}}], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Green}, {Style["a", 12], 
    Style["b", 12], Style["c", 12]}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: stacked plot revised]